# How do I copy a distribution zip file after it's been built using gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a Java application and I'm configuring the build using Gradle.

I believe this is the relevant part of my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'java'

build {
    version = new JsonSlurper().parseText(file('/path/to/metadata.json').text).version
}

distZip {
    archiveName project.name + "-" + project.version + ".zip"
}
```

So, I'm getting the version from an external source e.g. `metadata.json`.

I'm successful building the `build/distributions/projectName-version.zip`
 and I'd love to be able to create antoher zip file named `projectName-latest.zip` along with that. How hard could that be?

My Gradle knowledge is far from great, but I've spent too much time trying to find a way to insert a simple copy command with the two params right after `distZip` completes.

Answer (score 0):

For the copy itself, I recommend looking at the extensive [documentation on the topic](https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:copying_single_file_example). But in short, you will use a copy task.

As for triggering that task, you have different options, depending on what you want to achieve:

1. If you are used to invoke `assemble` or `build`, you probably want that same invocation to produce this additional archive. You could do that by having the copy task `dependsOn(distZip)` and `assemble.dependsOn(myCopyTask)`
2. If you are used to invoke `distZip`, then you could (slightly ab)use the `finalizedBy` concept and have `distZip.finalizedBy(myCopyTask)`. However this will run the copy task *even if distZip fails*.
3. Apply a combination of the two items above to cover all your bases.

Ideally, I would recommend going with 1, which works when invoking `assemble` or `build`.